# Automatic refresh of browser when I modify HTML or CSS in Visual Studio 2013 Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am testing Visual Studio 2013 Preview. The Browser Link feature (codenamne Artery) lets me update browsers I have opened to my web site using the Ctrl-Alt-Enter sequence.

At Build 2013, they demonstrated a feature of VS2013 Preview where the user can configure it so the running browsers automatically refresh whenever the HTML and CSS is modified.

How do I do that with Visual Studio 2013 Preview?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That feature isn't in the Preview build. It was an extension I wrote for a newer nightly build of VS2013. It will be available in the final release of VS2013

Comment: I was about to write that my VS2013 at work doesn't do this. While the one at home does and what the could be the difference. The difference of course is that I hadn't installed Web Essentials 2013 at work yet.

Comment: The [Web Essentials 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/56633663-6799-41d7-9df7-0f2a504ca361) extension is now available.

Comment: This is still not available. I tried changing a Razor view HTML but there's no automatic browser refresh. :( Am I wrong? I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 2 CTP and Web Essentials 2013 1.9.6 (from the nightly build channel).

Comment: It's only for CSS files. It's a whole different ball game to get HTML auto-sync working. We've started the effort and hopefully it will make it into a VS update

Comment: @MadsKvistKristensen is this available yet?

Answer (score 0):

Try live-server.
Very easy to install with node nmp 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server 
npm install -g live-server

Here it is on GitHub https://github.com/tapio/live-server

live-server does not work with razor.

NetBeans has a Chrome NetBeans Connector that works like a dream.
I don't understand why Visual Studio does not have this feature even with it's own browser.